# Why is my Linq to Entities code duplicating rows?

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, hierarchy

I'm using the ADO.NET Entity Framework to manage a hierarchy of objects.  Each has a single parent and zero or more children.

[ADO.NET Entity Framework Object with parent and children http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/7158/thingpi1.gif](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/7158/thingpi1.gif)

I present these in my WPF application with a TreeView control.  New Things may be added as children to the selected Things with the click of a button...

Visual Basic...

```
Private Sub ButtonAddThing_Click(...) Handles ButtonAddThing.Click
    Dim NewThing As New Thing
    NewThing.Id = Guid.NewGuid()
    NewThing.Parent = DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing)
    ...
    db.AddToThing(NewThing)
    db.SaveChanges()
    TreeViewThings.UpdateLayout()
End Sub
```

But, there's a problem.  Rather than simply adding a new Thing to the database, it's also first adding a duplicate of the parent, but oddly with an empty uniqueidentifier for an Id.

This clutters up the database and throws the following exception after the second click of button ButtonAddThing.

> Exception: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK_Thing'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Thing'.
>   The statement has been terminated."

These are the T-SQL insert statements generated...

The parent duplication:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Thing]([Id], [ParentId], ...)
values (@0, @1, ...) ',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 uniqueidentifier,...',
@0='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
@1='389D987D-79B1-4A9D-970F-CE15F5E3E18A',
...
```

The new thing:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Thing]([Id], [ParentId], ...)
values (@0, @1, ...) ',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 uniqueidentifier,...',
@0='88641EBB-B7D7-4203-8191-B27E1D1E1840',
@1='391FF0D9-40ED-4349-BB91-0F2E440EF8C9',
...
```

Why is my Linq to Entities code duplicating these parent rows?  How can I properly handle this parent/child relationship?

---

Update:  It's not just a problem when creating new Things.  My "delete" button isn't working properly either.

```
Private Sub ButtonDeleteThing_Click(...)
    db.DeleteObject(DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing))
    db.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

nor

```
Private Sub ButtonDeleteThing_Click(...)
    Dim Id As Guid = DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing).Id
    Dim DoomedThing As Thing = (From t In db.Thing _
                                Where t.Id = Id _
                                Select t).First
    db.DeleteObject(DoomedThing)
    db.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```

I'm monitoring the SQL Server Profiler while I debug my application.  Observed behavior:

1. The first button click deletes just fine.
2. The second button click inserts a duplicate-ish parent (empty GUID uniqueidentifier primary key) and then performs the delete.
3. The third button click fails (Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint) because it cannot insert a second Thing with an empty GUID primary key.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Dim ParentId As Guid = DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing).Id
NewThing.Parent = (From t In db.Thing _
                  Where t.Id = ParentId _
                  Select t).First
```

That will build the hierarchical model you are going for.

Comment: That was the nudge in the right direction that I needed.  Thanks.  It generates an extra select query now, but only the one insert.

Comment: No problem.  If ParentId is a field in your table, you should be able to do:

Dim ParentId As Guid = DirectCast(TreeViewThings.SelectedItem, Thing).Id
Thing.ParentId = ParentId
db.SaveChanges()
TreeViewThings.UpdateLayout()

No? It would save you the select.

Comment: Lost all the formatting I had, but I'm sure you can figure out what I was trying to say.  I never understood why in VB, the syntax used a newline to determine end of statement and not another character (like ";" in C#)

Comment: 'ParentId' is not a member of 'Thing'.  I can't just deal in GUIDs.